# Get private IP for Azure scale set VMs in Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

How can you get the private IP for a VM in am Azure scale set in Ansible?

None of these seem to have the info:

```
azure_rm_virtualmachinescaleset_facts
azure_rm_virtualmachinescalesetinstance_facts
azure_rm_virtualmachine_facts
azure_rm_subnet_facts
azure_rm_networkinterface_facts
```

Comment: how about virtual network facts? it should contain all the ip addresses assigned to thing that are attached to the vnet

Comment: Hmm. Nope, but it does provide [azure_virtualnetworks][subnets][0][properties][ipConfigurations] which is a list with the NIC interfaces for the actual VMSS instances, e.g. "id": "/subscriptions/60bb3a0e-150e-43f6-84cf-6c02e8506269/resourceGroups/testans_rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/testans-worker/virtualMachines/2/networkInterfaces/testans-worker/ipConfigurations/default"  So maybe I can use that somehow??

Comment: you probably can if you iterate over those. also its kinda weird instance facts doesnt provide that info

Comment: Nope so this is a dead-end. Neither the subnet nor the NIC facts contain these IDs. Looks like scaleset VMs are really special, at least to ansible.

Comment: yeah, well, they are special indeed, but you should be able to get their ips. you can use python sdk, for example

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the IPs of my ScaleSet instances, I take the little detour via the PrivateDNS of Azure with auto-registration. As soon as the machines are available, they will be updated in the DNS.

Code Snippet:

```
- name: Fetch IPs from ScaleSet instances
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    resource_group: "test-lbs1"
    vmss_name: "vmss"
    zone_name: "my.private.dns.zone"
  tasks:
  #############################################
  # Fetch all Instances from Scaleset
  #############################################
  - name: List all of the instances
    azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachinescalesetinstance_info:
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      vmss_name: "{{ vmss_name }}"
    register: __instances


  #############################################
  # Fetch IP from PrivateDNS Record
  #############################################
  - name: Get network interfaces
    azure.azcollection.azure_rm_privatednsrecordset_info:
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      zone_name: "{{ zone_name }}"
      relative_name: "{{ item.computer_name }}"
      record_type: A
    with_items: "{{ __instances.instances }}"
    register: __network_ips

  - debug:
      var: __network_ips
```